# WinRT-xaml-Toolkit: Line Series with median Line

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, silverlight-toolkit, winrt-xaml-toolkit

Is there a way to implement a median Line using this lib?

The only way I think could work is adding a new LineSeries and add a median for each Value in my Data-LineSeries

Something like this:

```
    <charting:Chart>
        <charting:Chart.Series >
            <charting:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}"  Title="Test Title" Height="400" Width="400" IndependentValuePath="dateTime" DependentValuePath="price"  >

            </charting:LineSeries>
---Pseudo----
            <charting:LineSeries x:Name="Median" ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}" Title="Median" IndependentValuePath="dateTime" DependentValuePath="median">

            </charting:LineSeries>
        </charting:Chart.Series>
    </charting:Chart>
```

This would cause me to add the median Value of my Product to each Article which is..kinda unnecessary.

Is there an easier way to do this? Or even a way which fills the space between Data and Median with a certain color (e.g. http://www.jidesoft.com/images/line-chart-gradient-fill.png)?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any built in statistical functions in the `DataVisualization` library that I ported from Silverlight Toolkit, but you can provide your own data source separate from your `Articles` one that has any range of values you want.

I also can't recall if the filled style of the data series visualization is implemented, but you could try to create a modified version of the `LineSeries` one that does support `Fill` or check the source if any such property is already available. It might be doable by simply changing the `Style` of the series.

Comment: To draw a Medianline accros the chart I would atleast an entry for Min/Max value of Datetime of my DataLine Series.

This would mean that I'd need an object with dateTime Min & median and an object with dateTime Max & median.

I think, this would be a little more elegant than my solution but still kinda awkward.

I'll look into the Fill thing though

Thanks!

P.s.

Pseudo works as well, see: http://i.imgur.com/R3GXjxF.png

Comment: As a sidequestion: Is there a way to set the "negative Start point" not 0?

I want sth like this http://i.imgur.com/CDn64gQ.png

On values below my median and not 0.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it's available out of the box, but you have the sources!